# How to make some items dividers in ionic 4 ion-list

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I’m trying to insert separators/dividers at certain spots in my list. I have the list bound to an observable, however some of the entries are seperators and I want to make them the ion-divider type.

I've tried several iterations of the code but while they appear, they are just normal clickable items, not dividers.

Previous:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item button *ngFor="let item of (results | async)" routerDirection="forward" routerLink="/{{ item.itemPage }}">
      <ion-label text-wrap>
        <h3>{{ item.name }}</h3>
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Now:

```
  <ion-list *ngIf="protocols">
    <ion-item button *ngFor="let item of (protocols | async)"  routerDirection="forward" [routerLink]="['/protocol-details/'+ item.id]" ng-class="{'item-divider':'true'}">

      <ion-label text-wrap *ngIf="item.type === 'P'">
        <h3>{{ item.name }}</h3>
      </ion-label>

      <ion-label text-wrap *ngIf="item.type === 'S'">
        <h3 style="color: red;">{{ item.name }}</h3>
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

The seperators are just normal clickable items, not dividers.  How can I make some of them non-clickable separators of, failing that, just non-clickable.

Comment: can you share your source data model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is making some items clickable and others not clickable. I suggest you can try something like that :

```html
<ion-list *ngIf="protocols">
    <ion-item button *ngFor="let item of (protocols | async)" ng-class="{'item-divider':'true'}">
      <div routerDirection="forward" [routerLink]="['/protocol-details/'+ item.id]">
        <ion-label text-wrap *ngIf="item.type === 'P'">
          <h3>{{ item.name }}</h3>
        </ion-label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ion-label text-wrap *ngIf="item.type === 'S'">
          <h3 style="color: red;">{{ item.name }}</h3>
        </ion-label>
      </div>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>
```

Comment: This almost is actually exactly what I ended up doing.